# React-router-dom v6, URL changing but component doesn't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I've tried everything but fail to render component when URL changes. No error messages nothing, it renders Home component but when i click on (view and edit icon)Link it just changes url, component does not render nothing happens. I couldn't find a solution, is there any way to make it work?

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
// import { TextFilledComp } from './Components/TextFilledComp';
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { SingleTodoPage } from "./Components/SingleTodoPage";
import { EditTodo } from "./Components/EditTodo";
import { Home } from "./Components/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <div>
          <div className="header-text">Todo List</div>
          <div className="box">
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/todo/:todoId" element={<SingleTodoPage />} />
            <Route path="/edit/:TodoId" element={<EditTodo />} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Todo.js**

```
import {
  Checkbox,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemSecondaryAction,
  ListItemText,
  makeStyles
} from "@material-ui/core";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import EditIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Edit";
import CheckBoxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckBox";
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  listRoot: {
    borderWidth: "1px",
    borderColor: "#aaaaaa",
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderRadius: "20px"
  }
});

export const TodoList = () => {
  const todos = useSelector((state) => state.todo);
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "95%", margin: "10px auto" }}>
      <List>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <ListItem key={todo.id} className={classes.listRoot}>
            <ListItemText primary={todo.name} />
            <ListItemSecondaryAction>
              {/* <Checkbox
                edge="end"
              /> */}
              <CheckBoxIcon color="primary" />
              <DeleteIcon color="secondary" />
              <Link to={`/edit/${todo.id}`} className="button">
                <EditIcon />
              </Link>
              <Link to={`/todo/${todo.id}`}>view</Link>
            </ListItemSecondaryAction>
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-hooks-hmcpl?file=/src/Components/TodoList.js:0-1374) link for complete app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Routes` component is the replacement for `Switch` from v5 and should only wrap around `Route` components. It's solely responsible for matching the provided paths and controlling the visibility of Routes and does not know what to do with regular JSX.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div className="header-text">Todo List</div>
        <div className="box">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/todo/:todoId" element={<SingleTodoPage />} />
            <Route path="/edit/:todoId" element={<EditTodo />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've also removed the `exact` prop as it is deprecated in v6 since all Routes are exact by default. To allow non-exact Routes, use the new `path="/nonexact/*"` syntax. Some more info on the new features can be found [here](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/).

Comment: i am following the exact same method,  you can see that too

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Paste in exactly the above into your codesandbox and it works. Your `Routes` component is incorrectly wrapping some `div` elements in your example. Also be aware that you have incorrectly capitalised the id of `path="/edit/:TodoId"` in your sandbox.

Comment: it was working with react-router-dom 5.1.2 but now i am moving to v6 and it is not working now, i have correct the spelling too

Comment: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-hooks-hmcpl?file=/src/App.js) updated codesandbox